# How to make a sticky navbar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, onscroll

I'm trying to make some code to make a sticky navbar, such that the position is fixed when I scroll down, however, it doesn't work. I wonder if the CSS is the problem, because most of the HTML and javascript would not really affect it. I have tried it on some of my other websites, and they work, but it doesn't seem to work on this one.

```
<div id="main-nav">
    <nav>
        <h2 id="logo" class="main-nav">Captain Max from ERA</h2>
        <br>
        <ul class="main-nav">
            <li> <a href="#">Listings</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#">Get in touch</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

The script for this is here, I'm not sure if anything is wrong with this though.

```
<script>
var navbar = document.getElementById("main-nav");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;
function myFunction() {
    if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
        navbar.classList.add("sticky")
    } else {
        navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
    }
</script>
```

The CSS is here, it seems like I made a property that altered how the sticky keyboard works.

```
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%
}

.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
    html {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

nav {
    background-color: #7b8195;
    color: #e9e6df;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#logo {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 250%;
    border-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 150px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

nav li {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

.main-nav {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin-right: 60px;
    border-bottom: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.main-nav li a {
    float: right;
    color: #e9e6df;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 90%;
}

.main-nav li a:link,
.main-nav li a:visited{
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    color: #e9e6df;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 90%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
    transition: border-bottom 0.2s;
}

.main-nav li a:hover,
.main-nav li a:active{
   border-bottom: 2px solid #e9e6df;
}
```

The link to the website is [here](http://captmaxproperties.com)

Comment: Shouldn't that be document.getElementById('main-nav') ? Also you dont need the same class on the h2 and the ul - you can use .main-nav ul to target the ul.

Comment: Oh, okay, thanks. I'll try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I can see here in your website is you havn't closed the `script` properly. You have missed one `closed }` brases.

```
<script>
var navbar = document.getElementById("main-nav");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;
function myFunction() {
    if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
        navbar.classList.add("sticky")
    } else {
        navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
    }
   }

</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll try that. Edit: It still doesn't seem to work though.

Comment: Did you made changes in your website ? As I can't see any changes .

Comment: Oh, I just tested it out on brackets. Going to upload it later along with a lot of other stuff.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I'm doing this for my friend, so its his website.

Comment: Don't forget to make a upvote https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

`Should I upvote the accepted answer?
If an answer has helped you solve your problem and you accept it, you should also consider voting it up if you have the reputation. If other answers have been helpful too, you can also vote them up. Unlike accepting an answer, you can upvote as many answers to your question as you like.`

Answer (score 0):

Everything is correct, but you have to add some CSS below to make it work.

```
<style>
#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: lightblue;
  color: black;
}

#navbar a.active {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Full code here:

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: lightblue;
  color: black;
}

#navbar a.active {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<div id="navbar">
  <a class="active" href="javascript:void(0)">Home</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">News</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">Contact</a>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <h3>Sticky Navigation Example</h3>
  <p>The navbar will stick to the top when you reach its scroll position.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I added CSS, just that I forgot to add it in... Thanks for the reminder! However, mine still does not really work.

Comment: Can you give me a suggestion please how would I add a sticky text box to the bottom left of the screen when the viewport changes to <1024px?